# C# List - Add to the bottom of the list

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List<T>` and want to start adding from the bottom but I'm getting a runtime `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I have initialized a list with a capacity:

```
List<ClassA> ClassesOfA = new List<ClassA>(10);
...
...
ClassesOfA[5] = classAObj;
...
```

Is there anyway to do this?

I need to do this because I'm analyzing another list from the bottom and adding the result to this list. So I need to be able to add from the bottom.
Is there any way to do this rather than initializing the `List<ClassA>` with `ClassA` objects before adding my objects?

Comment: Maybe it is `Stack` what your are looking for

Comment: Why not analyze the other list from the top instead of from the bottom.  Position is relative.

Comment: Defaulting the capacity does not pre-populate the list with items. It simply sets the current memory block for the list to save resizing if you happen to know the list size or a good initial size.

Comment: Let me add to what Adam said: It's that the `10` in `new List(10)` is a Capacity (a.k.a *reserve*), not Count (a.ka. the *size*). Don't trust your intuition. Read the docs :)

Comment: Thank you for your replies. No I cannot analyze from the top because I need to start from bottom and accumulate some values. And yes I realized that initializing with (10) doesn't help. When I inspected the object it said the list count=0 and capacity=10.

Comment: `No I cannot analyze from the top because I need to start from bottom and accumulate some values.`  That's not a reason at all.  If you think of the top as the bottom and the bottom as the top, then it would be fine.  You can either access the items in a reversed manor as well, or reverse the entire list when you're done adding.

Comment: @Servy You are absolutely right. I think it much easier for me reverse my original list, analyze from the top, adding to my second list from the top, and then at the end reverse both lists.

Comment: @madu Note that actually reversing a list (if it's not real small) has a bit of a performance cost.  It's quite likely that you just need to iterate the list in reverse instead.  Depending on what you're doing, it's also quite likely you want to use a stack.  You should at least look into that.

Comment: @Servy My List will be quiet small. Less than 20 items. But Stack implementation is what I need. Reason I wanted to use a List was because so the indexing of the elements of both lists will be the same. If I use Stack I need push/pop. But yes, Stack is what I really should use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try adding the elements like this: `ClassesOfA.Add(classAObj)`, then when all the list elements are added you can call `ClassesOfA.Reverse()` to reverse the order of the objects inside the list.

Comment: A better option would be to iterate over the original list in reverse order when adding the items to the new list. That would save the call to Reverse.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Note that if you use the LINQ `Reverse` and not `List.Reverse` then it will do just that, so all you need to do is `list.AsEnumerable().Reverse()`.

Comment: @macrosoaie Thank you. I didn't think about the reverse method. This could work for me.

Comment: @JustinNiessner the problem if you reverse the original is that you increase the complexity of the operation from O(1) to O(n). Which is fine if you only insert once, but if you are going to do that for every element, then populating the list becomes O(n^2)

Answer (score 8):

To add items to the list, you should be calling `ClassesOfA.Add()`. Any items added this way will be added to the end of the list (not sure if the beginning of the list or the end of the list is what you consider the bottom).

Comment: Although this is correct, I believe the OP is confused over the point of the `Capacity` constructor overload.

Answer (score 1):

If your second list will have the same number of elements than the first list that you're processing, I think what you want to use is just an array like:

```
var myArray = new ClassA[listA.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < listA.Count; ++i) myArray[i] = Process(listA[i]);
```

Comment: christ.. didn't you see the `new List<X>( otherIEnumerableOfX )` ? or `otherListOfX.ToArray()` method?

Comment: How is that related to anything? Of course you can do this in a lot of different ways, you could also just use linq like var myArray = listA.Select(Process).ToArray, but meh

Comment: negscore removed: I didn't notice the Process() call, with it, it makes at least some sense. If I had noticed it, I'd suggest that very Select :) Less chars = less to write = less errors. Less chars = Less to read = easier mainterance. Just that.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, and preferably, maintain two lists and concatenate them at the end:

```
var firstList = new List<ClassA>(); 
var secondList = new List<ClassA>();

// Fill the lists.

return firstList.Concat(secondList).ToList(); // using System.Linq;
```

---

However, if you really want to go the route you are suggesting:

You will need to add as many null items as you need in order to "reserve" the space:

```
var list = new List<ClassA>(10);
list.AddRange(new ClassA[5]);

// Or...
var list = Enumerable.Repeat<ClassA>(null, 5).ToList();
```

Now you can continue to `Add` items from index 5 onwards:

```
list.Add(new ClassA());
```

Capacity does not pre-populate the list with as many items. If you want to leave the first 5 empty, this is as best as I can see you'll get.

Add will append items to the bottom of the list from this point. I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to do it this way.

Comment: why to create an array of 1024 elements just to insert 1024 nulls? :) but, I admit, for small counts that's very brief. Still. I'd use Enumerable<X>.Repeat(5)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Well, its 5 for a start. I just used the array syntax as an array will default each element, which is what appears to be needed.

Comment: I've an IRC-based trait and press 'enter' usually one-sentence-too-fast. In the meantime you wrote yours, I've been finishing the comment. Of course, typos get everywhere, so it should be Enumerable.Repeat(x,5), but I think it's clear.. I wanted to point out that it's quite irrational to use manually tailored Capacity just to trash that small time/memory benefit by creating a throwaway array :) Either you care, or you dont. If you dont - leave the capacity out, let it adapt. If you care: then **do care**. It's minor thing, but it's the incosistency of logic that will later mislead someone.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Yeah, premature optimisation at best in any case. I personally think this is all an XY Problem, so tend not to care too much about the specifics so long as the requirements are met.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I prefer your method of adding nulls. I think the easiest two ways are initializing will nulls or reversing the list as reply above suggested. Thank you.